# UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES org.openrdf#sesame;2.3.1: not found

Tags: scala, sbt, sparql, sesame, openrdf

I'm trying to use spark with C-SPARQL in a sbt project,
I am getting unresolved dependencies errors when trying to build the project

```
[info] Resolving org.openrdf#sesame;2.3.1 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.openrdf#sesame;2.3.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/linux/.ivy2/local/org.openrdf/sesame/2.3.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openrdf/sesame/2.3.1/sesame-2.3.1.pom
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.openrdf#sesame;2.3.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.openrdf:sesame:2.3.1
[warn]        +- eu.larkc.csparql:csparql-sparql-sesame:0.1 (/home/linux/workspace/sbtC-SPARQL/plugins.sbt#L17-18)
[warn]        +- eu.larkc.csparql:csparql-core:0.1 (/home/linux/workspace/sbtC-SPARQL/plugins.sbt#L15-16)
[warn]        +- default:sbtc-sparql_2.10:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.openrdf#sesame;2.3.1: not found
```

I added some libraries in the pluguin.sbt file such as :

```
libraryDependencies += "eu.larkc.csparql" % "csparql-cep-api" % "0.1"

libraryDependencies += "eu.larkc.csparql" % "csparql-core" % "0.1"

libraryDependencies += "eu.larkc.csparql" % "csparql-sparql-sesame" % "0.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.fusesource.jansi" % "jansi" % "1.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "jline" % "2.10.4"
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274826/how-to-use-csparql-readytogopack-0-9-in-a-sbt-project

Comment: CSPARQL-ReadyToGoPack-0.9 contains a copy of the libraries it needs.  You cna use them from it's lib/ directory. See other question.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the version of openrdf you are using. It is not listed on [maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openrdf.sesame/sesame-runtime). You may try a newer version of the library

```
libraryDependencies += "org.openrdf.sesame" % "sesame-runtime" % "2.8.2"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) but it still doesn't work, I just wanna use the CSPARQL-ReadyToGoPack-0.9 http://streamreasoning.org/larkc/csparql/CSPARQL-ReadyToGoPack-0.9.zip in a sbt project

Comment: Ok, accoriding to this [site](http://streamreasoning.org/download) you shall add the dependency over eclipse. The drawback with this is that every time you build your project, the dependency will be deleted. If you have this library available as jar file you can add the library to the project's lib folder. SBT will consider every jar file in this folder as dependency. You can copy the library of the lib folder which is included in the zip file.