# how to use CSPARQL-ReadyToGoPack-0.9 in a SBT project

Tags: scala, sbt, sparql, sesame, openrdf

I want to use the  [CSPARQL-ReadyToGoPack-0.9](http://streamreasoning.org/larkc/csparql/CSPARQL-ReadyToGoPack-0.9.zip) in an SBT project. I'm on Linux. How can I do that?

Comment: Somewhat vague. Do you want it in the sbt build script or in project built with sbt. Is there a jar in there somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

In your build script you probably need to specify an artifact explicitly for the dependency (the module id parameters are jus):

import sbt._
import Keys._

```
libraryDependencies += 
  "foo" % "bar" % "0.1" artifacts Artifact("foo", url("file:/path/to/jar"))
```